# seaborn how do i create a box plot of only particular attributes in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, boxplot, seaborn

I would like to create two boxplots to visualize different attributes within my data by splitting the attributes up based on their scale. I currently have this

## box plots to show the distributions of attributes

```
sns.boxplot(data=df)
```

[box plot with all attributes included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yggnc.png)

I would like it to be like the images below with the attributes in different box plots based on their scale but with the attribute labels below each boxplot (not the current integers).

## box plots to show the distributions of attributes

```
sns.boxplot(data=[df['mi'],df['steps'],df['Standing time'],df['lying time']])
```

[box plot by scale 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw6DZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset a pandas DataFrame by indexing with a list of column names

```
sns.boxplot(data=df[['mi', 'steps', 'Standing time', 'lying time']])
```

Comment: @xjackx if the solution worked for you please "accept" the answer to mark the question as resolved

Comment: Hi @mwaskom  Can you please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595612/python-matplotlib-seaborn-boxplot-on-an-x-axis-with-data-points   I want to change some features from one of your answers, but i can't figure it out. Thanks!