# python/matplotlib/seaborn- boxplot on an x axis with data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot, seaborn

My data set is like this: a python list with 6 numbers [23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]

I want them to be be a horizontal box plot above an x axis with[23855 and 24472] as the limit of the x axis (with no y axis).

The x axis will also contain points in the data.

(so the box plot and x axis have the same scale)

I also want the box plot show the mean number in picture.

Now I can only get the horizontal box plot.
(And I also want the x-axis show the whole number instead of xx+2.394e)

Here is my code now:

`

```
def box_plot(circ_list, wear_limit):
    print circ_list
    print wear_limit

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0)
    plt.show()
```

`

[image]

Seaborn code I am trying right now:

```
def box_plot(circ_list, wear_limit):
    print circ_list
    print wear_limit

    #fig1 = plt.figure()
    #plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0)
    #plt.show()

    fig2 = plt.figure()

    sns.set(style="ticks")

    x = circ_list
    y = []
    for i in range(0, len(circ_list)):
        y.append(0)

    f, (ax_box, ax_line) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True,
                                        gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})

    sns.boxplot(x, ax=ax_box)
    sns.pointplot(x, ax=ax_line, ay=y)

    ax_box.set(yticks=[])
    ax_line.set(yticks=[])
    sns.despine(ax=ax_line)
    sns.despine(ax=ax_box, left=True)

    cur_axes = plt.gca()
    cur_axes.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this question in the other post as well, but I will paste it here just in case. I also added something that I feel might be closer to what you are looking to achieve.

```
l = [23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]

def box_plot(circ_list):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0, showmeans=True)
    plt.ylim((0.28, 1.5))
    ax.set_yticks([])
    labels = ["{}".format(int(i)) for i in ax.get_xticks()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    plt.show()

box_plot(l)
```

The result:

[image: Your box-plot]

Do let me know if it correspond to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much.. but this feel like it has very long whiskers. Can you please add the x axis (with points locate on the x axis) under the box plot? something similar to what I have in seaborn?

Comment: It has very long whiskers because your data has a high variance :). To add the x-axis, just remove this line from the code: ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')

Comment: I tried it does not work well. Let me clarify a little bit more on the question!

Comment: I have edited the question again. Thanks a lot for your help! @Andreq

Comment: And also I had a related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598654/matplotlib-python-same-code-generate-different-plots

Comment: @FrancicaZhao What is exactly that is not working? It looks like a very good answer to me.