# matplotlib/python Same code generate different plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I was asking for help in another question and when I try the answer's code I got a different picture. I really want my plot to be the same with the plot that was generated from the answer's author. I am using spyder/pycharm to generate the pictures.

I did not change any matplotlib general settings.

**The Code**

```
l = [23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]

def box_plot(circ_list):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0, showmeans=True)
    plt.ylim((0.28, 1.5))
    ax.set_yticks([])
    labels = ["{}".format(int(i)) for i in ax.get_xticks()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    plt.show()

box_plot(l)
```

**The answer's plot**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFilf.png]

**My plot**

[image]

This is the related question where I got the code from:(also not solved yet please help)

[python/matplotlib/seaborn- boxplot on an x axis with data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595612/python-matplotlib-boxplot-on-a-x-axis-with-clear-label-seaborn-is-also-welcome)

Comment: You may want to re-write your question. We do not know whT is meant by "I really prefer the plot that was generated from the answer's code." Just read the entries in [help] to understand how to write an effective question.

Comment: It's changed. @boardrider

Comment: You imported seaborn before generating your plot. That messes up all your matplotlib presets.

Comment: Show all your imports or your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mad Physicist [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598654/matplotlib-python-same-code-generate-different-plots#comment64620779_38598654), `seaborn` changes many styles and features of the plots:

**Code 1**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]

def box_plot(circ_list):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0, showmeans=True)
    plt.ylim((0.28, 1.5))
    ax.set_yticks([])
    labels = ["{}".format(int(i)) for i in ax.get_xticks()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    plt.savefig('box.png')
    plt.show()

box_plot(l)
```

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 2**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns            # <--- Only change!!

l = [23948.30, 23946.20, 23961.20, 23971.70, 23956.30, 23987.30]

def box_plot(circ_list):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.boxplot(circ_list, 0, 'rs', 0, showmeans=True)
    plt.ylim((0.28, 1.5))
    ax.set_yticks([])
    labels = ["{}".format(int(i)) for i in ax.get_xticks()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    plt.savefig('box.png')
    plt.show()

box_plot(l)
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]